# Gradle not building java application consistently

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

I am trying to understand gradle.

I followed the gradle tutorial here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_applications.html#what_youll_build

In short:

1. I created a folder: mkdir demo
2. cd demo
3. gradle init (so far so good)

Now, I tried to run my application like this: gradlew run.

The first run of the application was successful. However, the subsequent runs kept failing and I got a very non descript error.

```
> Task :app:run FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class demo.App

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Then, I deleted the files inside "Z:\Projects\demo\ .gradle\6.7.1\executionHistory" and I was able to run the application again.

This was happening again and again. Please see attached screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong -- how do I fix this so that all calls to 'gradlew run' give me a successful build?

**Edit:**

> I tried it on C: and was able to do 'gradlew run' consistently and get
> the 'Hello World' output without any issues. My Z drive is actually an
> encrypted VeraCrypt file which has been loaded with letter 'Z'. Not
> sure if that is causing problems.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue (using the same versions as you), so I think it must be something on your machine that interferes with the build. Is your Z drive a network drive? If it is, could you try on a normal drive (e.g. C)?

Comment: @BjørnVester - I tried it on C: and was able to do 'gradlew run' consistently and get the 'Hello World' output without any issues. Thanks!

My Z drive is actually an encrypted VeraCrypt file which has been loaded with letter 'Z'. Not sure if that if causing problems! What do you think?

Comment: That is very strange. I've used VeraCrypt before without issues, and I can't think of anything that would make Gradle behave in that way. Maybe it doesn't like the file system (exFat?) in the volume. I don't think many people have that use case so it is probably not worth spending too much time troubleshooting and fixing. But if it is important to you, you could create an issue for it in the Gradle Github repository.

Comment: Agreed - I don't want to troubleshoot this. I'll close this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I was facing the issue too, spend a lot of time and now I am sure, that the issue is the file system. I believe that your encrypted partition is using exFAT. Gradle is not able to process this file system properly.